# System.Console does not contain the definition for

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, windows-vista

So I have both Microsoft Windows and Millennium Edition. Both in different computers. My Vista works fine so as my ME. I have Microsoft.NET 4.5 installed on Vista, and, cause of the compatibility problems, I have 1.1 on Windows ME.
I really love console so as ASCII Text. My ME Computer doesn't seem to recognize some ascii characters, but that's not the big problem. When programming Console Applications, I, for example write `Console.ForegroundColor = Color.Black;` It seems correct right? My C# Compiler (CSC) says something like: `'System.Console' does not contain the definition for 'ForegroundColor'`. Same thing happen when writing `Console.BackgroundColor` and `Console.ReadKey()`. I use System, System.Timers, System.Text, System.Data, System.ComponentModel (just for test, because I only really need the first three ones). So the first thing I thought was, well, the fact that that .NET Framework version was old. So the question is: **What can I do?**

**NOTE:** My IDE is Notepad and/or Console's Edit. No Visual Studio.

Comment: What version of .net are you compiling against? 1.1?

Comment: Your title isn't good. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: The solution to your problem: Dump Windows ME... *SCNR*

Comment: Yes it's 1.1. Soner: Justin edited it. It was different.

Comment: Thorsten Dittmar - It's maybe the best computer I have ever had. I love it. Can't dump it. Not even .NET...

Answer (score 3):

If you are indeed running < .NET 2.0, then this property was not included in the .NET API

[Click here and choose the version dropdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) Notice the oldest is 2.0. It does not matter what version of the framework you have installed on the pc. It is about the version you compile against

Answer (score 2):

`ForegroundColor`, `BackgroundColor`, and `ReadKey` were all introduced in .NET 2.0. Compare:

- [System.Console in .NET 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [System.Console in .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You will need to compile against at least .NET 2.0 to get your code to work.

Comment: OH. I can't even beep. Oh no. Can I download .NET 2.0 for ME?

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480241.aspx) you should be able to... but if you have any troubles you might want to ask on http://superuser.com/